# How to build a function that loops through data frames and transforms the data in them (R)

Tags: r, excel, function, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to import data from an excel spreadsheet, only selecting a set of sheets (not all sheets) and then performing a few steps of data transformation (pivot longer and change data type).

I have got this in 4 lines of code and I could theoretically copy and paste this block for each sheet (8 in total), but I would like to see if I could loop through this all with a function.

The steps are the following:

1) Read the specific sheets and save them as data frames

2) Pivot longer taking columns 2:13

3) Change the new column values from excel date type (numeric) to the actual date

4) Change the date into yearmon format

Here is my code for doing this for one sheet:

```
kerrie <- read_excel("report.xlsx", sheet = "KERRIE_DATA") # load Kerrie data sheet
kerrie <- pivot_longer(kerrie, 2:13, names_to = "month") # put months into rows
kerrie$month <- excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(kerrie$month), date_system = "modern") # change date data type
kerrie$month <- as.yearmon(kerrie$month) # turn into yearmon
```

Here is a vector with all the sheet names

```
sheetNames <- c("KERRIE_DATA", "GAIL_DATA", "DANIELLE_DATA", "ISABELLE_DATA","ESTELLE_DATA", "CLARE_DATA", "JEN_DATA", "CHRIS_DATA")
```

And here is the solution I've found for step 1: it loops through the excel workbook and imports my desired sheets, saving them as data frames

```
library(openxlsx)
a <- loadWorkbook("report.xlsx")
for(i in 1:length(sheetNames))
{
  assign(sheetNames[i],readWorkbook(a,sheet = i))
}
```

Can you help me put steps 2:4 into a function/loop, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function with all the steps :

```
apply_fun <- function(sheet_name) {
     kerrie <- readxl::read_excel("report.xlsx", sheet = sheet_name) 
     kerrie <- tidyr::pivot_longer(kerrie, 2:13, names_to = "month")
     kerrie$month <- janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(kerrie$month), 
                      date_system = "modern") 
     kerrie$month <- zoo::as.yearmon(kerrie$month) 
     return(kerrie)
}
```

and apply it for all sheets

```
complete_data <- lapply(sheetNames, apply_fun)
```

This will return you list of dataframes in `complete_data`.

Comment: This did the trick and in case it was of help to anybody else, I then added the two following lines: complete_data <- setNames(complete_data, sheetNames) and list2env(complete_data,globalenv()). This saves each dataframe as an individual object with its proper name.